# can't change NIS account password from Centos-7 client “NIS server Centos-6”

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, nis, passwd

I'm trying to change password for a NIS account from a Centos-7.0.1406 client and the server is Centos-6.6

it seems that passwd command don't ask me neither to change password nor ask me for old password, it only returns the following

> Changing password for user mashour.
>
> passwd: Authentication token manipulation error

here is also strace snapshot

> open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = 5
>
> fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=520, ...}) = 0
>
> mmap(NULL, 520, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7fa11e121000
>   close(5)                                = 0
>
> open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> write(2, "passwd: Authentication token man"..., 48passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
>   ) = 48
>
> munmap(0x7fa114a82000, 2109664)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa114868000, 2200544)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa114664000, 2109648)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa114462000, 2101296)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa11425f000, 2105464)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa11405d000, 2101320)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa113e5a000, 2105576)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa113c54000, 2118240)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa113a49000, 2138640)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa113833000, 2183688)         = 0
>
> munmap(0x7fa113628000, 2138848)         = 0
>
> exit_group(1)                           = ?
>
> +++ exited with 1 +++

However I can change the NIS account password from any Centos-6 client using passwd command.

Any ideas what's going wrong ?

Comment: Don't you have to use yppasswd to change NIS users' passwords?

Comment: I tried yppasswd and it seems working fine, however i wonder why passwd isn't working on centOS 7